# why i am not able to insert row in table in joomla lovefatory extension

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

```
$trans='INSERT INTO xbq3a_lovefactory_memberships_sold values ('.$member[0].','.$member[1].','.$p[3].','.$member[3].',
"'.$member[4].'","'.$member[5].'",'.$member[6].','.$member[7].',
'.$member[8].',"'.$member[9].'",'.$member[10].','.$member[11].',
'.$member[12].','.$member[13].','.$member[14].','.$member[15].',
'.$member[16].','.$member[17].','.$member[18].','.$member[19].',
'.$member[20].','.$member[21].','.$member[22].')';

$this->_db->setQuery($trans);
```

member is one array retrieving data related to membership from database

Comment: There is no problem in data i am inserting in insert query i have tried it echoing and then run the query in database it runs but through code i am not able to insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Joomla you're using but assuming that `$this->_db` points to a Joomla Database object, i.e. and instance of `JDatabase` then your code has a few problems and is incomplete.

Long answer go and read the [Developer docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) on the [Joomla Docs site](http://docs.joomla.org/), specifically you will want to start with the "[Accessing the database using JDatabase](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)" article.

#### Shorter answer:

1. The reference to `xbq3a_lovefactory_memberships_sold` should be written as `#__lovefactory_memberships_sold` otherwise

   1. it will only ever work on one website that uses that prefix
   2. if the super admin changes the prefix later on your code will break.
   3. using the Joomla convention of `#__` for the prefix will make your code portable as Joomla automatically replaces the `#__` with the correct prefix for the current installation.
2. In the code you've posted you assign the query in `$this->_db->setQuery($trans);` to the db object but you don't actually execute it. To execute your query try adding `$this->_db->query();`

Comment: But when i use #__lovefactory_membership_sold instead of xbq3a_lovefactory_memberships_sold it doesnot insert data into table